# Let $f: X \rightarrow X$ be a homeomorphism of a compact metric space. If the orbit of $x$ is compact, then $x$ is periodic

Tags: real-analysis, dynamical-systems

Let $f: X \rightarrow X$ be a homeomorphism of a compact, connected metric space. If the orbit of $x$ is compact, then $x$ is periodic.

I feel like should be trivial, but I cannot seem to work out a proof.

Since $f(Orb(x)) = Orb(x)$ and $Orb(x)$ is minimal, it follows that $Orb(x)$ is nowhere dense.

Comment: What is the definition of the orbit? Is it include applying $f^{-1}$ as well? If not, then I don't see that the the image of the orbit under $f$ is itself, unless the orbit is in fact periodic.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming that the orbits are two-sided orbits consider the orbit $Y$ of $x$. This is a  countable compact metric space and $f$ is a homeomorphism of $Y$ onto itself. Write $Y$ as the  union of its singletons  and apply BCT to conclude that some point in $Y$ is open. This implies that each point of $Y$ is open because $f$ is a homeomorphism. Compactness of $Y$ implies that $Y$ is a finite set. [Look at the open cover formed by singletons].

Answer (score 4):

Kavi Rama Murthy's proof can be modified to work when the orbit $O=\{x_0,f(x_0),f(f(x_0)),\dots\}$ is one sided. As in their proof, some point $x$ in $O$ is open in $O$. This means there is an open $U\subset X$ for which $U\cap O=\{x\}$. This implies $f(x)$ is open as well, as
$$
\{f(x)\}=f(U\cap O)=f(U) \cap f(O)=(f(U)\setminus \{x_0\})\cap O
$$
Note $f(A\cap B)=f(A)\cap f(B)$ since $f$ is injective.

Supposing $x$ is not the initial point $x_0$, then

\begin{align}
\{f^{-1}(x)\}
&=f^{-1}(U\cap O)
\\&=f^{-1}(U)\cap f^{-1}(O)
\\&=f^{-1}(U)\cap (O\cup \{f^{-1}(x_0)\})
\\&=(f^{-1}(U)\cap O)\cup f^{-1}(U\cap \{x_0\})
\\&=f^{-1}(U)\cap O
\end{align}
The last equality follows since $U\cap O=\{x\}$, so $x_0\notin U$. This shows $f^{-1}(x)$ is open.

Therefore, the fact $x$ is open implies all points in the orbit are open, and you can conclude as in the other proof.